# File.delete() does not delete symlink on Android?

Tags: android

I can't delete a symlink on Android. Can't with `File.delete()` and neither with
`exec("rm " + verFile.getPath())`

I have a symlink

`com.example.app/mydata/12345.ver --> com.example.app/lib/library.so`

which was created by

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("ln -s %s %s", target, link));
```

After upgrade (download different build.apk from web) I want to delete this link by

```
File verFile = new File(dataDir, verFile);
Log.w("MyApp", "Deleting file " + verFile.getPath());
if (verFile.exists()) Log.w("MyApp", "File exists!");
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm " + verFile.getPath());
} catch( IOException ioex ) { Log.w("MyApp", "Failed to delete"); }
```

I can replace

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm " + verFile.getPath());
```

with

```
verFile.delete()
```

but it has no effect (the file still won't be deleted).

From the **adb logcat** I can see

```
W/MyApp   (13298): Deleting file /data/data/com.example.app/mydata/12345.ver
W/MyApp   (13298): File exists!
```

But the file 12345.ver is still there! It has the same user/group permissions as the rest of the application (except `lib` directory which is owned by the `system` user).

Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried 'rm -f' in the exec call?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is somewhat late, but google sent me here while trying to solve a similar problem. 
Any attempt to delete a particular symlink failed with the confusing message "directory not empty" 
I dug a little deeper, and found that the target file did not exist. I created one and rm worked :-).

Seems to me like a bug in Android, but I am too new to Android to be sure.